# What we can exactly do with debug_trace_call debug_trace_block_by_number debug_trace_transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethers.js, etherscan, geth-debugging

Could you please explain in detail the specific functionalities and use cases of debug_trace_call, debug_trace_block_by_number, and debug_trace_transaction and debug_traceCall? I am particularly interested in understanding how each of these methods contributes to debugging processes and what distinct features they offer compared to standard debugging tools

I would like to use them for my code but i don't know what their goal and we don't  have example about those functionnality.

Can someone please explain ?